# How to access static functions properly when method-chaining?

Tags: java

I haven't used Java in a long time and I'm having problems getting rid of a warning telling me to access static functions in a static way. I don't see how to do that in combination with method chaining.

```
options.addOption(OptionBuilder.hasArg().isRequired().withDescription(
                "DatabaseURL <jdbc:sybase:Tds:server:port/DB> required")
                .withLongOpt("dbURL").create("db"));
```

[image: warnings screenshot]

What is the proper way to configure Apache Options properly?

Comment: Note that `OptionBuilder` is deprecated - switch to the suggested `Option.builder` and all these problems go away :)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth ok, that seems a reasonable approach. Please post as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Javadocs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/OptionBuilder.html):

> Deprecated. 
>   since 1.3, use `Option.builder(String)` instead

`Option.builder` returns an object with non-`static` methods, which would circumvent this problem.

(In fact, it's very likely that it was deprecated because of exactly the grossness you're experiencing!)

Comment: Thanks, I was really weirded out by this, since I could not find a way to use this without creating tons of warnings or use a lot of statements.